# How To Recover from a Corrupted VS2022 Installation

Tags: visual-studio, vsinstaller

got a real conundrum here.  I was working on a WebAPI project yesterday, for which I needed to install ODP.Net, which I duly downloaded and installed from Oracle, also installed the ODP.Net NuGet package inside the Visual Studion project.  At this point everything went haywire with my VS session, which hung.  I then restarted VS only for it to prompt me for an activation code, which since I'm a subscription user it shouldn't be doing.  After a couple of failed attempts at this I then rebooted the machine and repeated to no avail.  At this point, I decided to try and repair and/or reinstall VS, only to discover that VS Installer is screwed as well.  I'm now stuck in 'no-mans land'.  Sort of trolling through the registry and removing VS elements manually to enable a re-install, I'm sort of stuck.  Has anybody else come across this situation, if so what is the solution, aside from me requesting IT for a re-imaging of my development machine

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Past a certain point it isn't worth spending a half-day or more trying to fix a hosed install of complex-software: your time is better spent nuking your box and doing a clean install of Windows and VS all in under an hour. So just do that.

Comment: @Dai And anything else that's on the machine too!

Comment: @phuzi as computing professionals, we should consider our machines _fungible_ and/or easily lost/stolen/breakable. With an appropriate strategy and plan it's not difficult to be in a situation where you can laugh-off something like your laptop being stolen off you during the middle of an EMP - and it _starts with_ having a working backup system and practicing disaster-recovery drills. It's a chore, but worth it.

Comment: @Dai Agreed, however not everyone is in a position to replace, or get a replacement up and running quickly. With an employer owned work computer, in my experience, it's often a struggle just to get administrator permissions so that you can install things like Visual Studio, git, etc. Getting to do a clean install of Windows on such a machine is likely still dependant upon other resources, most likely how friendly you are with the IT support staff.

Comment: As pointed out by @phuzi handing my dev machine over to IT means a painful process of getting the machine back to a fully productive platform... This may well be the eventual outcome, but I need to explore every possible avenue before I take the plunge :-)